# Bitwise_and function returning error assertion failed and mask is samezise

Tags: python-3.x, opencv

I'm trying to program a script that cuts out your face and makes all dark pixels become completely black. I begin by using a haarcascade to identify a face. Then I create a roi(region of interest) out of the coordinates from the haarcascade. After that I use an in range filter to select dark pixels and create a mask from that. Lastly, but not least I apply this filter to the cropped image to paste in my face.

The problem is that when I use bitwise_and function it returns an error. I can't understand the error, but when I've searched I've found people with a similar problem. The problem for me is that the answer is quite often not understandable or is just a reformatting of the code. I therefore wonder if you, the people of the internet, can answer in a way that makes it understandable for future readers(and also help me correct the code XD).

This is my code:

```
    import numpy as np
    import cv2


    face_cascade = cv2.CascadeClassifier('haarcascade_frontalface_default.xml')
    cap = cv2.VideoCapture(0)    
    while(True):

        #get's the cameras video
        _ , img = cap.read()
        #Converts to grayscale
        gray = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
        face = face_cascade.detectMultiScale(gray,1.3,5,1)
        if len(face) > 0:
            for (x,y,w,h) in face:
                roi = img[y:y+h, x:x+w]
            white = (255)
            grey = (75)
    #Finds dark pixel
            mask = cv2.inRange(gray,grey,white)
            res = cv2.bitwise_and(roi,roi,mask=mask)
            cv2.imshow('img',res)
        if cv2.waitKey(1) & 0xFF == ord('q'):
            break

    cap.release()
    cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

and this is the error:

```
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "C:\Users\molta\Documents\Pythons\Hologram2.py", line 23, in <module>
        res = cv2.bitwise_and(roi,roi,mask=mask)
    cv2.error: OpenCV(4.1.0) C:\projects\opencv-                
    python\opencv\modules\core\src\arithm.cpp:245: error: (-215:Assertion failed) (mtype == CV_8U || mtype == CV_8S) && 
    _mask.sameSize(*psrc1) in function 'cv::binary_op'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are getting above error because size of mask is greater than region of interest in your case. You are using `roi` which is a cropped version of the original image(cropped face) while `mask` is of size equal to the grayscaled version of the original image. They should be of same size. I think it should be something like below:

```
if len(face) > 0:
   for (x,y,w,h) in face:
        roi = img[y:y+h, x:x+w]
        img_gray = gray[y:y+h, x:x+w]

    white = (255)
    grey = (75)

    # Finds dark pixel
    mask = cv2.inRange(img_gray,grey,white)
    res = cv2.bitwise_and(roi,roi,mask=mask)
```